# Side menu disappears

Tags: bug, design

| Google Chrome | Microsoft Edge | Windows 10 Home |
| --- | --- | --- |
| version 98.0.4758.82 | version 98.0.1108.43 | version 21H1 |

If you scroll down the page and hover over any link, the side menu disappears when you return to the top of the page (Figures 1 and 3). The disappearance is also observed in incognito mode (fig. 2).

The phenomenon is detected by scrolling down to the words "Hire a developer" (you can go lower, but not higher). The menu does not change its distorted state until the pointer is moved, but if it was on a `left-sidebar` item, the state will change when you leave it. The menu items do not disappear smoothly, but in whole lines (first the word `Home` disappears entirely, then `PUBLIC`, etc.).

The change can be observed even without authorisation, but it requires removing the top bar (fig. 4) (via developer's tools or by using a standard cross). The selected menu item disappears one by one: first the text and then the background (fig. 5).

Presumably, the minimum page height should be 4814px ([matching page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)). But this is not only true for certain question pages, for example the general question list (50 questions per page) (Fig. 6) or the synonyms page (Fig. 7) are also subject to this change.

It is found that there is a minimum page scrolling speed. If the speed is insufficient, the menu will remain visible. It's also possible to get to a state where you don't have to remove the cursor from the link (fig. 8).

| [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Figure 1. Side menu disappears | Fig. 2. The problem persists even in incognito mode | Fig. 3. It is even possible to hover over a link in the same block | Fig. 4. Top panel of the unauthorised user |

| [image: enter image description] | [image: enter image description] | [image: enter image description] | [image: enter image description] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Figure 5. Intermediate state of disappearance | Fig.6. General question list | Fig.7. Synonyms page | Fig. 8. Interesting result |

## UPD

[Laurel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/323179/laurel) was able to repeat the phenomenon on Skeptics Meta using Google Chrome on Mac: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca9x2.png]

Comment: Unable to reproduce in firefox or chrome.

Comment: Are there others who can reproduce that behavior? Maybe those who upvote?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ This happens to me on an apparently random basis (and not on ru SO). But for some reason the steps here to reproduce it don't show the bug for me.

Comment: It's been over a month, but [I reproduced it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca9x2.png) on Skeptics Meta using Google Chrome on Mac.

Comment: @Laurel this is awesome, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to reproduce it intermittently (on Windows using Chrome, Brave and Opera GX; no repro on Firefox) on different SE sites — the first time I noticed this was before this question was posted.

The code below may help to repro on a [specific page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), I think the issue is both related to the scroll-up speed and to the page height. Sometimes the bug doesn't happen, so I refresh the page and try again.

Type this once on your [browser's console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + J</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd + Shift + J</kbd> to open the console):

```js
function scrollBug(delay = 0) {
  scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'auto' });

  setTimeout(() => {
    scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  }, delay);
}
```

Then just call the function with `scrollBug()` to test.

[image: It scrolls to bottom immediately, then scrolls up smoothly and the first link on the left sidebar is hidden when the scroll reaches the top of the page.]

When I scroll manually, sometimes all links are hidden. Using the script above, only the first one is hidden.

It's worth mentioning that my `window.outerHeight` is 864px, so the script may not work if your resolution is too different.

Comment: Thank you very much for your message. I'd just like to point out that your method involves *continuous* swiping, but a real person with a computer mouse in his hand is unlikely to be able to provide that. I want to point out that I observe the disappearance both when using a touchpad and when using a regular computer mouse (so I didn't specify the source of the input)

Comment: But it could be a clue. Perhaps it is not the speed of swiping that should be monitored, but its frequency

Comment: I know it's different, I just shared this code because it worked to repro the bug on the mentioned page, and maybe it help the developers to debug. I also did a more complex code to simulate scroll-stop-scroll (like a person would do using a mouse), but the results weren't any better.